# GMaps: Dozens of entries at same address

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a page I am building that will take 'contacts' that I have in a database, and take their geo-coded addresses and display them on a Google Map using the v3 API.

An issue I am now tackling relates to having multiple (dozens in some cases) contacts at the same address. I'd like to be able to have the typical callout/overlay that could display their Job title, etc when the marker is clicked, but when the same marker effectively represents lots of people, I am struggling to handle this as the markers are all layered on top of each other, with only the last one that was placed (at the top of the stack, so to speak) responds and shows that individuals data.

I've searched for a solution, but I am not really coming up with anything (maybe I am using the wrong terminology). Does anyone have any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up implementing the following on my v3 map - works perfectly for my needs:

http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/06/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/