# Google Maps API - Markers with duplicate latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I have a map that shows up to 30 markers, all loaded from the store database table upon user query.
the table has couple of thousand stored in it.

**Problem:**

Some latitude and  longitude in database are duplicate, which are needed.  when these are plotted on the map they overlapping each other. Resulting the user cant see all the markers,  these need to be clicked by the user to show more info and etc.

**Question:**
Is is possible to show on the map, those hidden markers?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GMaps: Dozens of entries at same address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873567/gmaps-dozens-of-entries-at-same-address)

Comment: @geocodezip  thanks, that was the answer i was after.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and [clustering](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) was no option beacuse the markers had the exact same latitude and longitude. I've also tried the [spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) lib but i did not like it very mouch because the user could not see ho many markers were at one point at a glance.

In the function that adds the markers to the map I looped over my markers-array and compared the position of the markers. If they had the same lat & lon I added a little offset.
Almost like the solution in the first answer of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15436/google-markers-at-same-address-not-showing-all-markers) thread.
Now the markers are not in the same position, but still overlapping. So i added a "mouseover" event to raise the z-index of the marker. See [here](http://biostall.com/bring-google-map-marker-to-front-on-hover).

Hope this helps! happy coding

Answer (score 2):

If the marker have the same coordinates, then they will be placed in the same location.
This is a normal behavior, this is how it works.

The solution for you problem should be not to show the hidden markers, but ratter on receive of icon that has same coordinates as an icon that already appears in the map, edit the current marker in the map and add to it the data of the new marker you want to set.

That way the current marker would represent both stores.